# An idea: Make writing MyBatis (Java Spring) SQL code as *simple* as writing Django/Laravel?

Tags: java, python, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

In one line: (I hope I can) **Write code like dynamic language (Laravel/Django), and enjoy the performance in Java**.

We know it is very *verbose* to write down MyBatis codes... For instance, as a toy example, the following MyBatis code:

```java
public interface CommentDao {
    @Select(
      "SELECT * FROM comments"+
      "<foreach collection='blogIds' item='id' open='(' separator=',' 
close=')'>"+
        "#{id}"+
      "</foreach>"+
      "AND id <= #{pageStart}"+
      "ORDER BY id DESC"+
      "LIMIT #{pageLimit}"
    )
    List<Comment> getComments(List<Integer> blogIds, long pageStart, int pageLimit);
}
```

Which IMHO is *toooooooooooooooooooooooooo long* :(

So I propose the following: We only need to write down very simple Python (or PHP, to be determined) code:

```py
def getComments(blogIds, pageStart, pageLimit):
    comments.select()
        .whereBlogId(blogIds)
        .page(pageStart, pageLimit)
```

and it will *automatically generate* the big MyBatis code above (by e.g. one-click `python generate.py`)!

Remark of the above code -

1. Those `.whereBlogId`, etc, are all statically-typed (by code generator), so using PyCharm or Intellij IDEA you will have the powerfulness of code completion.
2. As for how the code simplifies - (i) The long `<foreach>` is completely gone; (ii) We write by *semantics*, instead of *syntax*. Thus we do not need to say three things `WHERE id<=start` & `ORDER BY id` & `LIMIT limit`. We only need to say the semantics `page()`.

Of course, this is just a simple example. I just want to illustrate the potential of this approach (Python/PHP generator + MyBatis) :)

---

**Question**: Is my proposal good? Or will it have some problems that I did not see?

Thanks for any suggestions!

<sub>p.s. I have researched other solutions like JOOQ, MyBatis Plus, MyBatis Generator, etc. But IMHO none has the good properties above... If needed I can provide more about that</sub>

Comment: Please take a look at https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/ - I think it is close to what you are proposing.

Comment: @JeffButler Thanks! I have seen that before. My main concern is that, strangely few people are talking about this library on the Internet, so I am not sure I can get enough support when using it when seeing problems... So what do you think about that? Thanks!

Comment: All I can say is that this library is relatively new, and the integration with MyBatis generator is also relatively new. I'm interested in any feedback you might have about it.